# Yocto extra image feature seems to be not in the image

Tags: yocto

I've started to work with the Yocto project on a raspberry pi 3 and therefore followed the instructions in [this guide](https://www.codeinsideout.com/blog/yocto/raspberry-pi).
It adds the dropbear ssh server for remote access

`EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES_append = " ssh-server-dropbear"`

After the creation of the image I checked the image manifest and it seems like dropbear has been added.

```
dropbear aarch64 2019.78
```

But it seems like when I run the image the application is not really there. I'd expect something inside `/etc/init.d/` but there are no `dropbear` artifacts.

Also, altough the python meta-layer should be added, the `py/python` command is unknown on the target.
Can someone tell me what exactly I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not specifying why you believe dropbear is not part of the image, if it is present on `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES` (and you even see it in the manifest) I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be there, perhaps you are looking for it in the wrong location?

If you can post an update with the actual error you are getting that would help.

`python3` does not come from the meta-python layer, it is part of the core layer (meta), meta-python contains other python related recipes which extend python's functionality.

To install python3 on your image do:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "python3"
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the python thing... just wondering why they add it in their guide in the first place when python is not installed. Regarding dropbear I updated the question.